# Bundling and Minification Issue with MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I am using Bundling and Minification in an asp.net MVC4 project which is hosted on a server. Due to certain reason Bundling and Minification is not happening and cant figure out why? As a result the original css file is being loaded which makes the site very slow.

Any help will be appreciated

**Bundle class is as follows**

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/layoutStyle").Include(
            "~/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css",
            "~/plugins/dist/css/AdminLTE.css",
            "~/plugins/dist/css/skins/skin-purple-light.css"
            ));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(("~/bundles/layoutScript")).Include(
           "~/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.js",//jQuery 2.1.4
           "~/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js",//Bootstrap 3.3.5
           "~/plugins/dist/js/app.js"// AdminLTE App
           ));         
    }
```

**Layout page of the website is**

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/layoutStyle")

  <!-- REQUIRED JS SCRIPTS -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/layoutScript")
```

**The pagesource of the website hosted is** 
[image]
[image]

**Webconfig in release version**

```
 <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
```

Comment: Have you disabled optimisations in code? For example this code: `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;`

Answer (score -1):

The bundles are rendering as designed, but not bundling. This is the behaviour one would expect if the website was running in debug mode. The bundling only happens in release mode. Check your web.config for `debug=true`. If it is there, remove it.

Comment: Sorry my answer is badly worded. The assemblies need to be compiled in release mode and the debug attribute removed.

Comment: However, that's not true. The compile mode doesn't change whether bundling happens.